# Is the set of continuous maps on $[0,1]$ with finitely many roots open in the $C^0$ topology?

Tags: general-topology, continuity, roots, transversality

Let I would like to show that the set $$S=\{f\in\mathcal{C}([0,1],\mathbb{R}):f\text{ has finitely many zeros}\}$$ is open. By considering $f_n(x)=\frac{x}{n}$, we see that $S$ is not closed. By applying the transversality lemma to $F(x,\theta)=f(x)+\theta$, we find that $S$ is dense. I am hoping to show that $S$ is open. I know that if $f$ is transverse to $\{0\}$ and $g\in\mathcal{C}([0,1]^2,\mathbb{R})$, then there exists an $\varepsilon_g$ such that $f+\varepsilon g$ is tranverse to $\{0\}$ for every $\varepsilon\le\varepsilon_g$. However, this is not good enough to show openness of $S$ because $\varepsilon_g$ depends on the direction $g$. I found an infinite-dimensional version of the transversality theorem [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transversality_theorem) that would show that $S$ is open but I am hoping there is an approach with a simpler set of conditions to check than the one in the link.

Comment: Is $\mathcal{C}([0,1], \mathbb{R})$ given the uniform norm here? If so, it seems that $S$ would not be open.

Comment: In fact, every open subset of $\mathcal{C}([0,1], \mathbb{R})$ (sup/uniform norm/metric) contains many functions that are nowhere differentiable, although not necessarily with graphs that intersect the $x$-axis. However, if we restrict ourselves to the metric/normed subspace of continuous functions having at least one zero, then every open subset of that subspace contains continuum many functions each of which has continuum many zeros. See Theorem 2 in [*How many zeros does a continuous function have?*](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2323473) by Tomás Domínguez Benavides (1986).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, the set $S$ is not open!

Consider say the function $f(x)=x$ for all $x\in I:=[0,1]$, and any arbitrary $\varepsilon\in(0,\frac12)$.  Note that the function $g\in C^0(I)$ defined by
$$
g(x)=\begin{cases}
0 & x\in [0,\varepsilon]\\
2(x-\varepsilon) & x\in [\varepsilon,2\varepsilon]\\
x & x\in[2\varepsilon,1]
\end{cases}
$$
satisfies $\lVert f-g\rVert_{C^0(I)}=\varepsilon$ and $g\notin S$.